# Oracle 11g XE import

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

When I upload a `*.cvs` file into Oracle Express using the data upload tool, the column mapping changes. I have uploaded the same data before, to test things out.

I then deleted all the data in the table and now want to load in fresh data for further testing. The mapping looks good in the `*.cvs` file before I upload it but when I get to the last step the columns have changed position in the `*.cvs` file.

Any idea why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Perhaps put an example of how the columns are switching?  Is it random or is there a pattern?

Comment: Is it a `cvs` or a `csv` file?